# Neo4j. Create constraint to count of relationships having type "RT"?

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher

I use this code to get paths between nodes `a` and `b` that contain two and less relations `RT`.

```
MATCH (a:Tes1 { title: "a" }),(b:Tes1 { title: "b" }), p=shortestPath((a)-[r:BT|RT*]-(b))
WITH count(type(r)='RT') as cnt
WHERE cnt < 3
RETURN p;
```

error:

> Type mismatch: expected Relationship but was List (line 2, column 17 (offset: 111))
>   "WITH count(type(r)='RT') as cnt"

I know that this error means but I don't know another way.
Please, help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot count a specific type of a collection, you need to filter it and get its size :

```
MATCH (a:Tes1 { title: "a" }),(b:Tes1 { title: "b" }), p=shortestPath((a)-[r:BT|RT*]-(b))
WITH p, filter(x IN relationships(p) WHERE type(x) = "RT") AS rtRels
WHERE size(rtRels) < 3
RETURN p;
```